# Column names: "_address_middlename" are invalid?

Tags: magento

I am getting this error while uploading files in magento build in customer import feature.
Its really frustrating.

> /*
>   _address_middlename,firstname,lastname,email,password_hash,middlename,_address_firstname,_address_lastname,_address_street,_address_postcode,_address_city,_address_country_id,_address_region,_address_telephone,created_at,_website,_store,created_in,group_id,reward_update_notification,reward_warning_notification
>   1,John
>   ,Vlahides,JohnVlahides@earthlink.net,0f685c57363a378127e7487e5b670d403e013a8a69d1d6b7863b2a54e9d41b73:Nd,,Richard,Simmers,301
>   Pebble View Ln #8,28726,East Flat Rock,US,North
>   Carolina,828-692-6959,7/27/2010 2:26,base,default,Default Store
>   View,1,0,0
>   */

the above one is working but the following one is not working

> /*
>   address_middlename,firstname,lastname,email,password_hash,middlename,_address_firstname,_address_lastname,_address_street,_address_postcode,_address_city,_address_country_id,_address_region,_address_telephone,created_at,_website,_store,created_in,group_id,reward_update_notification,reward_warning_notification
>   1,testered,testered,test@test.com,testered,,testered,testered,11
>   Coned,11213,Moded,US,North Carolina,none,2004-03-01
>   15:15:00,base,default,Default Store View,1,0,0
>
> */

what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

My guess is password field. It probably should be an MD5 hash of the password with a salt like in the one that works 0f685c57363a378127e7487e5b670d403e013a8a69d1d6b7863b2a54e9d41b73:Nd. Also the dates for created_at are in different formats and can telephone number have a value of none, might need to be just empty instead. Replace the values I have identified above with the ones from the working example and test one by one until you narrow down the exact field causing the issue and correct your data file accordingly.

Comment: NO I got the solution. If you upload customer using import then you need to change the file format ANSI ,you can use editplus to do it.